# Change the content of a page from a wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress

I am creating a payment gateway for woocommerce and it works great.

Now I need to change the content  of the thank you page so I think that is better to create one of my own.

I have a folder with the page that I want to show inside my plugins under a "templates" folder, si my idea is to show that one.

I still not able to show the content of that website. Any ideas on how to do this ? I would be really greatful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, the best solution was to have functions / shortcodes that do some stuff before loading the pages and then redirecting to the pages.

At least this worked for my plugin.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/webpay-woocommerce-plugin/

Any way, if you want to change the content, you could add a website through the plugin calling the following methods.

```
get_header();
get_footer();
```

With those 2 functions I could call everything that I needed to create my website page withing my plugin.